# Rails undefined method for array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

In my controller I am trying to run a query to get all of the id's not referenced in another table like so:

```
@vlan_numbers = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT pop_vlans.id, vlan_number FROM pop_vlans WHERE pop_vlans.id NOT IN (SELECT logical_interfaces.vlan_id FROM logical_interfaces) AND pop_id != " + @pop_id.to_s)
```

Then in my view I am trying to use `collection_select` to show these in a dropdown menu:

but the error I get is `undefined method 'vlan_number' for [2, "2"]:Array` where those values are just the first row of results from the query.

This is a diagram of the two tables involved:

```
logical_interfaces | pop_vlans
-------------------|-----------
     vlan_id-------|----->id
       ....        |  vlan_number
```

and the relationships in the models are:

**pop_vlan.rb**

```
belongs_to :logical_interface
```

**logical_interface.rb**

```
# no relationship defined
```

**Update**

This is how the form is generated:

```
<%= form_tag :controller => "circuit", :action => "update" %>
    # other inputs
    <%= select_tag options_for_select(@vlan_numbers) %>
    # other inputs
 </form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `select` with `options_for_select(@vlan_numbers)` instead of `collection_select`

results from `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` doesn't get loaded into a model

Instead you could try `YourModelName.find_by_sql(...)` If you want to play with your model

**UPDATE**
Assuming the name of your attribute you want this `select_tag` to populate is `vlan_id` so:

```
<%= form_tag :controller => "circuit", :action => "update" %>
  # other inputs
  <%= select_tag 'vlan_id', options_for_select(@vlan_numbers) %>
  # other inputs
</form>
```

Comment: thanks but using `<%= select options_for_select(@vlan_numbers) %>` gives the following error message - `wrong number of arguments (1 for 3)`

Comment: or `select_tag` may be… depends on how you're building your form if you are using `form_for` then `f.select :vlan_id, options_for_select(@vlan_numbers)` given that `f` is the instance of your form builder

Comment: do you mean `<%= select_tag options_for_select(@vlan_numbers) %>`? Using that, my select menu isn't populated with any options.

Comment: can you provide us some snippets on how you are generating your form?

Comment: @jo3w, I've updated the question, each input is just manually inserted into the view via an appropriate helper function such as `text_field` or `check_box`

Comment: yes, that's the one, it's *almost* perfect but for some reason the id and vlan_number have swapped, so the `id` is the option text and the `vlan_number` is the value when it should be vice versa, can't see why that's happened though?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35416/discussion-between-j03w-and-martincarlin87)

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` returns `Mysql2::Result` not array of object as Arel/AR query does.

So it returns array of arrays containing  `pop_vlans.id, vlan_number`. So have to use first or last in your collection_select instead of `something.vlan_number`

### So you have to use `options_for_select` instead of `collection_select` like:

```
options_for_select(@vlan_numbers.collect{|v| v.first})
```

Comment: thanks but I'm not quite sure what you mean, do you have an example?

Comment: sample output of `@vlan_numbers = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT pop_vlans.id, vlan_number FROM pop_vlans WHERE pop_vlans.id NOT IN (SELECT logical_interfaces.vlan_id FROM logical_interfaces) AND pop_id != " + @pop_id.to_s)` could be [[1,3], [2,3], [4,5], [3,1]]. so if you  use [[1,3], [2,3], [4,5], [3,1]] in collection_select you have to operate on array so  you should not find `vlan_number` in array

Comment: I think I know what you mean now, so, next question would be, how to get the last member of each array? e.g. using your example, `3,3,5,1` but bearing in mind I would need the first member of each array to act as the value of the select.

Comment: @martincarlin87 see the api http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-collection_select